# Debugging BlueZ dbus proxy objects and signals

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, iotivity

I was looking in a way to debug signal coming from BlueZ. Currently I am trying to debug a problem I am facing with a framework (Iotivity) and was looking in a way to debug the proxy dbus objects and its signals.

The problem is that I have a method that is connect to the g-properties-changed signal of a characteristics (GATT) proxy object that should be fired when I receive data from my device. [This](https://github.com/iotivity/iotivity/blob/1.1-rel/resource/csdk/connectivity/src/bt_le_adapter/linux/client.c#L279) is the line of code that I am talking about. I can see the data coming from the btmon and hcidump tools but that callback never gets called.

So the main question is, is there a tool to debug dbus signals and proxy objects. A tool that I can use to fire a signal or see the signals being fired ?

Here are some logs that might be useful. (BlueZ, Iotivity and hcidump logs)
http://pastebin.com/FWcRE3Uz

**Edit:**

I got the dbus-monitor to work. After some more reading I understood that there are 2 types of bus and that I had to specify that I wanted the system bus: `dbus-monitor --system "type='signal',sender='org.bluez'"`

The problem now is to find why the method in question is not being fired even though the signal is, as you can see in the log I got from dbus-monitor:

```
signal sender=:1.5 -> dest=(null destination) serial=273 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C7_6A_A9_0B_DD_5F/service000c/char000f; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "Value"
         variant             array of bytes [
               d8 c6 45 48 8a 23 f3 c4 9f a2 77 b3 6f 69 63 03 72 65 73 11
            ]
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

Comment: are you looking for dbus-monitor, this can help you to get the methods or signals invoked

Comment: @ashish I tried dbus-monitor, but the board that I am using to develop doesn't have a display and I get the error: Failed to open connection to session bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11. I am using ssh btw.